# Running .NET Core 2.0 framework dependent deployment on Raspberry

Tags: .net

I have created a .NET 2.0 Core app with Visual Studio and deployed it to my Raspberry Pi 3 using the self contained publish option - see the excellent instructions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/setting_up_raspian_and_dotnet_core_2_0_on_a_raspberry_pi/).  It runs fine.  The project's target framework is ".NET Core 2.0".

My question is: how do I run a framework dependent deployment of this app on my Raspberry?  I tried using "dotnet publish" to create a FDD but when I run it on my Raspberry with "dotnet HelloWorld.dll" I receive an error:

> The specified framework "Microsoft.NETCore.App", version '2.0.0' was
>   not found.

So apparently installing the .NET Core runtime on the Raspberry doesn't include the NETCore.App framework.  Can the framework be installed on the Raspberry and if so, how?

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6581

Comment: Thanks, Uwe.  I'll see if the suggestions there help.