# .Net Core 2.0 Framework Dependent Deployment on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: deployment, .net-core, raspberry-pi3

I am in the process of understanding .Net Core and have created a simple console application. I have installed the one pre-requisite that is required in Raspbian Stretch which was libunwind8 via the command:

`sudo apt-get install curl libunwind8 gettext`

and am able to run my console application in self contained mode, but when I download and install the .net core 2.0 latest runtime (2.0.5), I am not able to run the same application in the framework dependent mode. I get an error message suggesting the following:

> The specified framework "Microsoft.NETCore.App", version '2.0.0' was not found.

The error message suggests that Microsoft.CSharp.dll is missing while I can see that installed in the folder where .net core runtime has been installed.

Either I am doing something wrong or .net core applications in RPi cannot be yet run in framework dependent deployment mode. The official instructions also do not indicate explicitly anything about FDD execution mode, [available here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md).

Can anyone please help. A similar question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025549/running-net-core-2-0-framework-dependent-deployment-on-raspberry), but has gone un-answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to create fdd in your case, because according [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/index) "fdd relies on the precence of a shared system-wide version of .net core". I have a similar pain- win10 iot at the present time have only net core 1.0 preinstalled